# module 'dask' has no attribute 'read_fwf'

Tags: python-3.x, dask

I want to use dask.read_fwf(file), but I get there error

```
AttributeError: module 'dask' has no attribute 'read_fwf'
```

The same problem occurs for read_csv and read_table.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled dask, as well as trying to rename my 'csv.py' file in \dask\dataframe\io. The same problem occurs after both of these attempted fixes.

pd.read_fwf and the like work fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You wanted [`dask.dataframe.read_fwf`](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.read_fwf)

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
dd.read_fwf
```